# Exception in thread “main” java.util.InputMismatchException "Temperature program"

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point, inputmismatchexception

Can someone help with this? I can get it to run, but after the output message "What is the outside Temperature:" "Number here"

Type (C) for Celsius or (F) for Fahrenheit:

Once I type in C or F it gives me this error message

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Tem.main(Tem.java:13)
```

Please Help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tem 

{

    public static void main(String [] args) 

    { 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String unit = ""; 

                System.out.print("What is the outside Temperature: "); 
                 double temp = scan.nextDouble(); 

                System.out.println("Type (C) for Celsius or (F) for Fahrenheit: "); 
                int input = scan.nextInt();

                if (input == 'F')
            { 
                    temp = (temp - 32) * 5/9.0; 
                    unit = "Celsius."; 
            }           
                else if (input == 'C')
         { 
                temp = (temp * 9/5.0) +32; 
                unit = "Fahrenheit."; 
         }

    System.out.println("It is "+temp+" degrees "+unit);

    }

}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc for `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `"C"` and `"F"` aren't valid `int`s, so that is the source of the `InputMismatchException`.  But you want a letter, so you should call `next()` instead of `nextInt()` to get the next token.

The [`next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) will return a `String` that you can see if it's `equals` to `"C"` of `"F"`.

Comment: Or get the `charAt(0)` and compare as characters.